# SQL - Returning combinations of ID from tables if combination not found in another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have four tables of interest: users, models, questions and labels.

"Labels" contains rows that describes a user's answer to a question on a model. e.g username TEXT, mid INT, qid INT, answer TEXT

I am interested in finding out what model-question pairs the user is still required to provide. A user is asked to provide an answer for every combination of model and questions that appear in their respective tables. So for a given username, I can have rows of model ids and question ids.

Users:

- Bacon, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, ...
- Mark, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, ...

Models:

- 1, climateOne, XXXX, ....
- 2, climateTwo, XXXX, ....
- 3, climateTwo, XXXX, ....

Questions:

- 1, "Is this a question?"
- 2, "And another?"

labels:

- Bacon, 1, 2, "Yes is was..."
- Bacon, 3, 2, "Another what?!"

So the result of asking "what model question pairs has 'Bacon' not completed" would be the return of:

(1,1)(2,1)(2,2)(3,1)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results -- preferably in tabular form in the question.

Comment: It may also be helpful to provide an attempt at the query. Easier to correct what's already there than to try and imagine what you're after in the first place.

Comment: Well, I have no idea whether to try and start with one of the outside tables and join the labels on, search for overlaps and remove or the other way round. I've not gotten any intuition on where to start :( I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks go to CL. for the point in the right direction. This code worked for me as I was using python's sqlite3 package. I have included the username specification too. However, I have no clue whether it is efficient or not :)

```
SELECT m.mid, q.qid
FROM models m CROSS JOIN questions q
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM labels l 
    WHERE l.username = ? AND l.mid = m.mid AND l.qid = q.qid
)
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

To get all possible combinations of models and questions, use a cross join:

```
SELECT models.id,
       questions.id
FROM models
CROSS JOIN questions
```

Then filter out those that have been completed:

```
...
WHERE (models.id, questions.id) NOT IN (SELECT mid, qid
                                        FROM labels);
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, I was able to adapt it to fit the situation and have posted what I have made because of it.